# How to access Xeround's database remotely by using php? Is it possible to show on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, xeround

I am new to Php and Xeround Stuff.. I want to make a database remotely, for that I am using [Xeround Services](http://www.xeround.com), Now I want to make a php file on my system and want to access the database made on xeround.. Its help says we can do it using :

```
<?php
  $con = mysql_pconnect("instance123.db.xeround.com:4567","john","malon");
  if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("mydb");

  // rest of the code . . .
?>
```

My problem is:

How to access it from my computer? What do I need to install to run the php page? Shall I install WAMP? But whats the use of WAMP when I am remotely accessing PHPMyAdmin for MySQL, or do I need to install Apache Server only? Or what shall I do? I am confused.

I basically want to run a query from my computer by accessing xeround's database. I don't have a website so localhost would be used to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can just get an account over at [phpfog](https://phpfog.com/) which is basically the same cloud database but includes php app hosting. If your new maybe this is a nicer route for you. You can also add your [Xeround to the phpfog](http://www.appfog.com/products/phpfog/add-ons/) as an addon.

> How to access it from my computer? What do I need to install to run the php page? Shall I install WAMP?

Yes you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) too. You can run scripts in your local apache/php. Or you can run PHPmyadmin (through apache/php after you install WAMP) which might be easier. Or even some local software like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) but for all that it might be neccessary to [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) access to your ip address.

That code you posted goes right into a php script. Do you know php?

Comment: Thanks, But I need to use remote Database, that is why I was preferring Xeround.
Secondly phpfog requires a registration fee to add addons like Xeround. Now what shall I do?
Actually, I want to practice cloud computing, therefore would like to make database on xeround while running queries from my own system

Comment: I already told you in my answer; Setup WAMP, create PHP scripts to run queries or use something like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench. -- Also FYI you don't need to use xeround with phpfog, phpfog already provides an included free database and the whole thing is in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

To access your database on Xeround remotely using PHP, you must first verify that you have the php-mysql module installed. To install it in Linux, run the following command:

```
yum install php-mysql
```

To verify you have the `php-mysql` module you will need to prepare a file called `phpinfo.php` with the following content:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Now, run

```
php -f phpinfo.php
```

Another option you can consider is accessing phpMyAdmin from the Xeround UI (then the connection string to the database is sent to phpMyAdmin).

Good luck :)